# How to import a huge list of content in XML into Liferay?

Tags: liferay

I am new to Liferay. I am working on a task, in that I need to convert the list content in XML to liferay article. In short, I am converting huge list of content into Liferay article.

I have developed a portal, through that I am importing a content into liferay. During importing time,few minutes successfully import the content into liferay. After few minutes, I got below exception. I have tried many times to import, But I failed to import complete content into liferay.

```
importing:java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Aug 27, 2015 9:38:16 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException

atcom.liferay.portal.service.permission.PortletPermissionImpl.contains(PortletPermissionImpl.java:305)
atcom.liferay.portal.service.permission.PortletPermissionImpl.contains(PortletPermissionImpl.java:226)
atcom.liferay.portal.service.permission.PortletPermissionImpl.contains(PortletPermissionImpl.java:211)
atcom.liferay.portal.service.permission.PortletPermissionImpl.hasAccessPermission(PortletPermissionImpl.java:436)
atcom.liferay.portal.service.permission.PortletPermissionUtil.hasAccessPermission(PortletPermissionUtil.java:278)
atcom.liferay.portlet.SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.hasAccessPermission(SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.java:344)
atcom.liferay.portlet.SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.check(SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.java:209)
atcom.liferay.portlet.SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.checkRender(SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.java:243)
atcom.liferay.portlet.SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.render(SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.java:139)
atcom.liferay.portlet.RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.render(RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.java:126)
atcom.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerUtil.render(PortletContainerUtil.java:156)
atcom.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer._render(PortletRenderer.java:125)
atcom.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer.access$4(PortletRenderer.java:107)
atcom.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer$PortletRendererCallable.doCall(PortletRenderer.java:180)
atcom.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer$PortletRendererCallable.doCall(PortletRenderer.java:1)
atcom.liferay.portal.kernel.executor.CopyThreadLocalCallable.call(CopyThreadLocalCallable.java:69)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
atcom.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask._runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:682)
atcom.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:593)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

09:38:16,735 ERROR [http-bio-9001-exec-134][status_jsp:753] javax.servlet.ServletException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround of this, you can consider increasing the max queue size:

```
index.search.writer.max.queue.size=9999999
```

Also, you can add the following which makes disk writes less often:

```
lucene.commit.batch.size=10000
lucene.commit.time.interval=300000
```

You can consider referring this [defect](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-54672) notes for more information.

Cheers!
AJ

P.S. This is just a possible workaround or tuning thing, but I think there would be a better solution somewhere in case the above is not.